# Why I can't send request from one localhost to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, http

I want to send request from one localhost to another localhost running on this same machine.
First is `localhost:3000` and second `localhost:3005`.

Belowed code is from maching `:3005` which is trying to send request to `:3000`:

```
return new Promise<EventResponse>((resolve, reject) => {
    const httpOptions= {
      hostname: "http://localhost:3000", //not working also without http/https
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/api/something',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    }
    const request = http.request(httpOptions, (res: IncomingMessage) => {
      res.setEncoding("utf8");
      res.on("error", reject);
    });

    request.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("ERROR: ", err); //ENOTFOUND
      reject;
    });

    request.on("timeout", () => {
      request.destroy();
      reject({
        statusCode: 400
      });
    });

    request.write(JSON.stringify(payload));
    request.end();
  });
```

Can someone tell me why above code throw me this:

```
ERROR:  Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1:3000
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '127.0.0.1:3000'
}
```

I'm sure that `:3000` server is running during sending this request.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When you open `localhost:3000` in the browser, does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: it says that it cannot find a host named `127.0.0.1:3000`, and that is perfectly understandable, since the colon character `:` is illegal in hostnames, IPv4 addresses, and IPv6 addresses.

`3000` is the port number, not part of the hostname. You have to pass `3000` as the port and `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as the hostname:

```typescript
const httpOptions= {
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 3000,
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/api/something',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
}
```

Note that the same applies to `http://` as well: forward slashes `/` are also illegal in hostnames, IPv4 addresses, and IPv6 addresses. HTTP is the protocol, it is not part of the hostname. HTTP is the default protocol for [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback), so there is no need to pass it. If you want a different protocol (e.g. HTTPS), you have to pass it:

```typescript
const httpOptions= {
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 3000,
  protocol: 'https:',
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/api/something',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
}
```

If I had to take a guess, I would say that the root cause of the problem is that you are confusing a URI, a hostname, a protocol, and a port. But that is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
const httpOptions= {
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 3000,
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/api/something',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't declare the `port` or `protocol` in the `hostname` like that.
Modify your `httpOptions` like so:

```
const httpOptions= {
   hostname: "localhost",
   port: 3000,
   method: 'POST',
   path: '/api/something',
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
}
```

You can read more on the `httpOptions` here: [Node HTTP.request([options])](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequesturl-options-callback)